# methods definition in gdb without having the source

Tags: c++, gdb, ddd-debugger

I have a **debug build without sources** to start with.
`ptype` gives me the class definition with the prototype of methods declared in it.

```
(gdb) ptype A

type = class A : public B {

  private:

    int c;


  public:

    virtual void accept(Ivisitor &V);

    virtual int getItem(void) const;

}
```

How can I get the the definitions of methods `accept()` and `getitem()` in gdb ?

Please note I don't have the source with the debug build.

```
(gdb) l A::accept

Line 469 of "const.h" starts at address 0x433d9c <A::accept(Ivisitor>)> and ends at 0x433db1 <A::accept(Ivisitor>)+21>.
```

Answer (score 1):

U can not view function definition without attaching a source code. Class definitions are seen as symbol table was loaded.

Comment: Yes. Debug build does information does not include source code. If you don't have it you cant display it.